# How to auto deploy latest image from Cloud Build in Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, continuous-deployment, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

My [CI/CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration#Deploy_an_artefact_from_CI) pipeline for deploying my [Angular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework)) app is close, but I see that Google Cloud Run does not deploy a new revision when the container image has been updated.

I have Cloud Build set to trigger a build when a branch on GitHub has been updated. That is working fine and I see I get a new image named after the commit hash. I'm expecting Cloud Run to trigger its service, pick up the latest image and deploy it, but it's not running. I'm not sure if I need to change the image names so they are not unique due to the [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) hash value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a Cloud Build step to deploy the new image to Cloud Run.

Modify this example with SERVICE_NAME, REGION, PROJECT_ID, and IMAGE.

```
# Deploy container image to Cloud Run
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  entrypoint: gcloud
  args: ['run', 'deploy', 'SERVICE-NAME', '--image', 'gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE', '--region', 'REGION', '--platform', 'managed']
```

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-cloud-run)

Comment: It looks like this requires a cloudbuild.yaml file. I use a Dockerfile and the UI shows I can't do both...?

Comment: @JeremySchultz - Dockerfile is for the container build step. I provided a link to documentation on a full example which includes building the container in a separate step. If you are not using a Cloud Build YAML file, create one so that you can specify the steps to build and deploy.

Comment: @JeremySchultz on the build yaml file, you can specify a step to build your container image, as demonstrated here: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-containers#use-buildconfig

Comment: Thanks John and Dondi, this triggered Cloud Build and then Cloud Run and both were successful. I do need to keep the Dockerfile for the container build step, right? The yaml code doesn't refer to it but I think that's because it's in the same directory.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue while using Terraform and got around it by tagging the image with the `COMMIT_SHA` variable ([which is available in all cloud builds by default](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values)) and referencing that in the `.tf` files I was using.

The tagging step:

```yaml
  - id: 'Tag image'
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args:
      - 'tag'
      - '${_IMAGE_NAME}'
      - '${_ARTIFACT_REGISTRY_REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/${_PROJECT_ID}/${_ARTIFACT_REGISTRY_REPO}/${_IMAGE_NAME}:${COMMIT_SHA}'
```

The push step:

```yaml
  - id: 'Push image'
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args:
      - 'push'
      - '${_ARTIFACT_REGISTRY_REGION}-docker.pkg.dev/${_PROJECT_ID}/${_ARTIFACT_REGISTRY_REPO}/${_IMAGE_NAME}:${COMMIT_SHA}'
```

The application step:

```yaml
  - id: 'Apply Terraform changes'
    name: 'hashicorp/terraform'
    args:
      - 'apply'
      # other vars I was using
      - '-var'
      - 'image_tag=${COMMIT_SHA}'
      - '-auto-approve'
```

In the terraform I created a local variable for the image like so:

```
locals {
  image = "${var.artifact_registry_region}-docker.pkg.dev/${var.project_id}/${var.artifact_registry_repo}/${var.image_name}:${var.image_tag}"
}
```

Which I then referenced in the `google_cloud_run_v2_service` definition in Terraform.